# Not able to access child window using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

**Control identifiers**
[image]

I am trying to automate the process to decrypt the file using kleopatra application using pywinauto library. I'm able to connect and the access the element from the main window, but not able to get hold of the new window that pops up.

I want to access the new windows element and open a file from that window whose title is "Select One or More Files to Decrypt and/or Verify".

Here is what I'm doing in the code, but getting the error.

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend='uia').start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\bin\kleopatra.exe").connect(title="kleopatra",timeout=100)

fileMenu = app.kleopatra.child_window(title="File", auto_id="MainWindow#1.file.file", control_type="MenuItem").wrapper_object()

fileMenu.click_input()

# app.kleopatra.print_control_identifiers()

decryptMenu = app.kleopatra.child_window(title="Decrypt/Verify...", auto_id="KXMLGUIClient-KActionCollection.file_decrypt_verify_files", control_type="MenuItem")

decryptMenu.click_input()

selectFileWindow = pywinauto.application.Application(backend='uia').connect(title = "Select One or More Files to Decrypt and/or Verify")
```

How can I connect to new window?

**Error**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -
`selectFileWindow = app.window(title = "Select One or More Files to Decrypt and/or Verify")`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.window(title_re=".*Part of Title.*")
```

[If the title of the dialog is very long - then attribute access might be very long to type, in those cases it is usually easier to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gym8c.png)